# Automatically incremented column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first

Let's say I have the following Entity Framework entity:

```
public class FileDownload
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FileTypeId { get; set; }

    public int FileHeaderId { get; set; }
}
```

I want the FileHeaderId to work like a bit like a primary Key by for each FileType that is downloaded.

So I'd like the following structure record structure:

```
 ID    FileTypeId        FileHeaderId

 1         1                   1
 2         1                   2
 3         2                   1
 4         2                   2
 5         3                   1
 6         3                   2
 7         3                   3
 8         1                   3
 9         2                   3
10         1                   4
```

Is there anyway this can automatically be set when the records is saved?

I don't want to do lookups to find the last id then increment it by 1.

The FileHeaderId is used within each file and must be unique for each file type.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to generate a **customer specific** order number? Why not have a order number which doesn't rely on the customer id?

Comment: That is my requirement

Comment: What's the purpose of OrderNumberForCustomer?

Comment: The short answer is - its hard. You'll need to have a unique index to deal with the inevitable collisions (and C# code to do retries). You'll need to do the lookup you want to avoid. You'll need to consider edge cases like 'what happens if I delete an order for a specific customer?' (i.e. order number reuse). All of this is why most systems don't work this way - they don't use **customer specific** order numbers.

Comment: have you tried setting [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute?

Comment: I agree with the others... but if you must, why not store an 'OrderIndex' of sorts where the CustomerId comes from? That way you can increment that when there's a new order and grab the value to use when creating a new order.

Comment: OK, forget the customer order id. That was just a dummy class I typed to explain the problem

Comment: @maulikkansara - That doesn't work as I already have a primary key and it won't be unique for each type

Comment: @Sun Perhaps (FileTypeId, FileHeaderId) should be the primary key instead.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft How will the FileHeaderId auto increment?

Comment: @Sun having removed ID, you could use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] .  It wouldn't repeat for each FileTypeId, but you could always display it that way in a report.

Comment: `OK, forget the customer order id.` The general problem is the same though. Renaming the column to something else doesn't solve the concurrency etc issues that I mentioned in my earlier column.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But I need the value to increment individually for each file type

Comment: Why would you "need" that?  Change the "requirement", and use a simple, scalable design.  Also any way to achieve what you want would be database specific, and we don't know what database you are targeting.

Comment: As each file file is downloaded it is marked with a headerid that must be sequential. The file is read in at an external source and that is the requirement.

So each type must be 1,2,3,4,etc

Comment: Could that ID be calculated at generation (download) time rather than insert time?

Comment: I did think that but there is a risk of a duplicate number being created. That's the reason I want it to work like a primary key#

Comment: How would a duplicate number be created at generation time?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your requirement to not use sequence number and instead use Guid or Date, than you'll have to do 1 of

1. Lookup to get last sequence number in code.
2. Or have a database trigger or something in the database to set correct sequence number.

There are some considerations with regards to #1:

1. Can the records be deleted? Would reusing sequence number be a problem?
2. Do the records get created by multiple threads. If yes, you can't be sure, that incremented last sequence number is indeed the last one, you might need another table just to sync/lock the indexes so that they are not taken twice or more.

---

I'd still suggest to revisit the architecture, because with current approach you might have too much unnecessary complexity that can be avoided by changing table schema a bit.